# Node language in views contextual filters

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have a multi-lingual site. On the article page has a block with other articles. How to bring in the article section with the same language as the current node? Interested in is the use of contextual filters. Option of using the language of the current user filter is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't the current users language suitable, that's what you want

Have you looked in the filters section of views (Bottom left of the views editing screen) rather than contextual filters? There should be the current users language as a filtering option in there.

Comment: I have to show this block when editing or creating node. In this case, the user's language and nodes language use different.
is to bring

Node type article have field "similar articles" type of entity reference.
When creating node a language is not defined, and I think that this is unlikely to happen. But editing node anguage is defined, and is possible as that to implement. I want the impossible?

Comment: I don't think you'll do this with views alone. You could create a custom block in code that worked out the nodes language and then programmatically retrieved the views block while passing it the nodes language as a filter.